# largest independent set in a circuit of length $n$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

largest independent set in a circuit of length $7$ and $n$?

For $7$, I guessed it's $3$.
Guidance on finding for $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: two cases, odd and even.

Comment: can you elaborate? the book just says it's "incredibly difficult to find maximum independent sets" >_>

Comment: In general it's incredibly difficult, but in this case it's easy.  Start with the case where $n$ is even.  Can you find an independent set of size $n/2$?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, some definitions. An independent set is a set of vertices without an edge between any two vertices. A circuit is a sequence of distinct vertices $v_1, v_2, \ldots, v_n$ with each pair of consecutive vertices joined by an edge and the last edge running from $v_1$ to $v_n$. So if our independent set includes $v_1$, then it cannot include $v_2$, but it can include $v_3$. And if we include $v_3$, then we can include $v_5$. By this logic, our set contains every other vertex starting from $v_1$. So our set is $\{v_1, v_3, \ldots, v_{n-2}, v_n\}$. But then we have an edge from $v_n$ to $v_1$. No problem, just get rid of $v_n$. But consider $n = 6$. Then our set will be $\{v_1, v_3, v_4\}$ when it should be $\{v_1, v_3, v_5\}$ (you can verify this by inspection). So our set is $\{v_1, v_3, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$. But consider $n = 7$. Then our set should be $\{v_1, v_3, v_5\}$ but our logic gives us $\{v_1, v_3, v_5, v_6\}$. So we have two cases. Our set should be $\{v_1, v_3, \ldots, v_{n-1}\}$ when $n$ is even and $\{v_1, v_3, \ldots, v_{n-2}\}$ when $n$ is odd.